# Potentials and Poisson equation

Tags: poissons-equation, potential-theory

Ok so I am very confused about these types of questions and tutorial solutions miss out a load of working so if someone could explain how to do this question in a very basic manner I'd really appreciate it!

Q: Solve the 2D Poisson equation for an azimuthally symmetric ($\theta$- independent) potential in polar coordinates,

$$\frac1r\frac d{dr}\left(r\frac{d\Phi(r)}{dr}\right)=-\rho(r)$$

where

$$\rho=\begin{cases}a-r&,r\le a\\\\0&,r>a\end{cases}$$

subject to the boundary conditions $\Phi(0)=0$ and $\lim_{r\to \infty}\frac{\phi(r)}{r}=0$

Answer (score 0):

> **GENERAL APPROACH:**

By directly integrating and applying the condition $\Phi(0)=0$ we find that

$$\Phi(r)=-\int_0^r \frac1{r'} \int_0^{r'}r''\rho(r'')\,dr''\,dr'\tag 1$$

Changing the order of integration in $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\Phi(r)&=-\int_0^r r''\rho(r'')\int_{r''}^r \frac1{r'} \,dr'\,dr''\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^r r''\log(r''/r)\rho(r'')\,dr''}
\end{align}$$

---

**Case for $\displaystyle \rho(r)=(a-r)u(a-r)$**

If $r<a$, then

$$\begin{align}
\Phi(r)&=\int_0^r r''\log(r''/r)(a-r'')\,dr''\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac19r^3-\frac14ar^2}\tag 2
\end{align}$$

If $r>a$, then

$$\begin{align}
\Phi(r)&=\int_0^a r''\log(r''/r)(a-r'')\,dr''\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{a^3\left(\frac16 \log(a/r)-\frac5{36}\right)}\tag3
\end{align}$$

---

> **DIRECT APPROACH:**

Another way forward is to write for $r\le a$

$$\frac1r\frac d{dr}\left(r\frac{d\Phi(r)}{dr}\right)=-(a-r)\tag 4$$

Then, multiplying $(4)$ by $r$ and integrating we find that

$$r\frac{d\Phi(r)}{dr}=-\frac12ar^2+\frac13r^3\tag 5$$

Dividing $(5)$ by $r$ and integrating we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\Phi(r)=-\frac14 ar^2+\frac19r^3} \tag6$$

which agrees with $(2)$!

For $r\ge a$, we can write

$$\frac1r\frac d{dr}\left(r\frac{d\Phi(r)}{dr}\right)=0\tag 7$$

Then, multiplying $(7)$ by $r$ and integrating we find that

$$r\frac{d\Phi(r)}{dr}=a\frac{d\Phi(a)}{da}\tag 8$$

Dividing $(8)$ by $r$ and integrating we find that

$$\Phi(r)=a\frac{d\Phi(a)}{da}\log(a/r)+\Phi(a)\tag 9$$

Using $(6)$ to find $\Phi(a)$ and $\frac{d\Phi(a)}{da}$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\Phi(r)=a^3\left(\frac16 \log(a/r)-\frac5{36}\right)}\tag{10}
\end{align}$$

which agrees with $(3)$!

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it, can you put it any simpler?

Comment: @SFL I just provided the full solution.  What is it that is causing the problem?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Comment: hi sorry for late reply. I don't really get Then, multiplying (7) 
 by r onwards